# Datasource JNDI lookup on wildfly failed with Connection refused error

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, datasource, jndi

I deployed an ear containing a war and a jar module on Wildfly 21.0.1.Final. I have configured jndi as follows in standalone.xml

```
 <datasources>
  <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MyDS" pool-name="MyDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
      <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@mc300xxx:1524:DEV</connection-url>
      <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
      <driver>oracle</driver>
      <security>
          <user-name>xxx</user-name>
          <password>xxxx</password>
      </security>
      <validation>
          <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker"/>
          <background-validation>true</background-validation>
          <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker"/>
          <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
      </validation>
  </datasource>

  <drivers>
      <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle.ojdbc6">
          <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
      </driver>
  </drivers>

</datasources>
```

### Jndi lookup code

```
private static final String JNDI_NAME = MyDB;
private static final String PROVIDER_URL = "remote://mc300xxx:4447";
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory.class.getName());
properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,PROVIDER_URL);
Context ctx = new InitialContext(properties);
DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:jboss/datasources/"+JNDI_NAME);--> Error here
con = ds.getConnection();
```

### Stack trace

```
0:08:45,441 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 115) *javax.naming.CommunicationException: WFNAM00018: Failed to connect to remote host [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]

10:08:45,441 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 115)  at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteNamingProvider.getPeerIdentityForNaming(RemoteNamingProvider.java:110)
10:08:45,441 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 115)  at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteNamingProvider.getPeerIdentityForNaming(RemoteNamingProvider.java:53)
10:08:45,441 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 115)  at org.wildfly.naming.client.NamingProvider.getPeerIdentityForNamingUsingRetry(NamingProvider.java:105)
10:08:45,442 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 115)  at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteNamingProvider.getPeerIdentityForNamingUsingRetry(RemoteNamingProvider.java:91)
10:08:45,442 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 115)  at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteContext.lambda$lookupNative$0(RemoteContext.java:189)
10:08:45,442 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 115)  at org.wildfly.naming.client.NamingProvider.performExceptionAction(NamingProvider.java:222)
10:08:45,442 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 115)  at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteContext.performWithRetry(RemoteContext.java:100)
10:08:45,442 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 115)  at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteContext.lookupNative(RemoteContext.java:188)
10:08:45,442 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 115)  at org.wildfly.naming.client.AbstractFederatingContext.lookup(AbstractFederatingContext.java:74)
10:08:45,442 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 115)  at org.wildfly.naming.client.AbstractFederatingContext.lookup(AbstractFederatingContext.java:60)
10:08:45,442 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 115)  at org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyRootContext.lookup(WildFlyRootContext.java:144)
10:08:45,442 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 115)  at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
10:08:45,442 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 115)  at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
10:08:45,442 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 115)  at com.xim.mss.java.dao.common.oracle.DbConnection.getConnection(DbConnection.java:71)
10:08:45,449 INFO  [com.xim.mss.java.dao.common.oracle.DbConnection] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 115)  EXIT :: com.xims.java.dao.common.oracle.DbConnection.getConnection()10:08:45,449 ERROR [com.xims.framework.batch.util.Utils] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 115) Error in getConnection() java.lang.NullPointerException
```

When I am trying datasource jndi lookup in wildfly getting ConnectionRefused error.
Can anyone tell me how to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: If this is all running in the same deployment is there a reason you're doing a remote lookup?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins There is no reason for doing a remote lookup. I am migrating my application from JBoss 5 to WIldfly 21. During deployment I got this error.   javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0027: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory from classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module . After going through the wildfly jndi documentation (https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Remote%20JNDI%20Reference.html), I did the changes.

Comment: This error got resolved after changing the provider url from "remote://mc300xxx:4447" to "mc300xxx:1100"; @JamesR.Perkins Thanks for the point remote lookup